# Enkompass - running a site on VPS without domain name

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I have Enkompass setup on a test VPS that does not have a domain pointed towards it.

How would I be able to create and test some PHP web applications, and have them work from port 80 from the IP of the VPS?

Ex. 111.111.111.11/mytestapp/

Creating a new account in Enkompass didn't seem to create a new site in IIS, and I don't know how to actually view a test site.
I'm not using Enkompass for reselling purposes, I am just hosting some personal PHP web applications.